# how is my webrtc audio is being heard when all elements are muted?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

In my webrtc application there are two video elements and both are muted. Both the candidates engaged in a webrtc chat has 2 peer connections. When one to one is happening everything is working fine, But as soon as the other peer connection kicks in, Even though all elements are muted, I am still able to hear the sound of the sender to himself
How is it even possible..?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: It's a quite lengthy piece of code..as I am using a webrtc server to process my SDP named KURENTO..Nonetheless, How is even possible to hear a sound in webrtc when all your elements are muted ?

Comment: Your question basically says "My Car won't go even when I press on the gas". This is going to be impossible to solve without all the code.

Comment: All you should show is your client side code and the elements that are "muted"

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. It's surely some bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my issue after days of trial and error, Turned a problem of the SDP, I just changed 'a=sendrecv' in my sender's SDP to 'a=sendonly' for Senders.